# Create multiple buttons with Angular in a loop

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable "options" that contains a list `['a', 'b', 'c']`, and like this is displayed on the `<h3>` below.

Now I want to create a button for each element in the list, with the index appended to the `id` and as the `value`, and displaying the text in the button.

This is my code, but however I only get an empty button. What's wrong?

```
<h3>{{options}}</h3>
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/" ng-repeat="i, option in options">
    <button id="button{{i}}" type="submit" value="{{i}}">{{option}}</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** I made my code easier and it still doesn't show any of the 3 options in the `<span>` but it shows properly the list in the `<h3>`. Is it perhaps something that I need to install in order to run `ng-repeat`? I have the `angular.min.js` in the `<head>`

```
<h3>{{options}}</h3>
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/" ng-repeat="option in options">
    <span>{{option}}</span>
</form>
```

I have this in the header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try grouping `(i, option)` in parentheses?

Comment: I just did and still fails. I edited my question with an easier example that still fails.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's just the missing brackets. Should be `ng-repeat="(i, option) in options"` in your case.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

**UPD** Also `ng-repeat` should be an attribute of `<button>` in the first example and of `<span>` in the second one. Unless you want 3 forms on the page.

Comment: Seems that it still fails. I edited my question with some further info

Comment: Oh I see. You need to move `ng-repeat` to `<span>` tag. Angular makes multiple instances of a tag `ng-repeat` is attribute of. @Arturo

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have the correct list in the options array and then try using it like

```
<h3>{{options}}</h3>
<form id="choice" name='form' method="POST" action="/" ng-repeat="option in options">
     <button id="button{{$index}}" type="submit">{{option}}</button>
</form>
```